# Selector in custom class

Tags: swift, selector

I wrote a custom button which is basically a `NSView` subclass. The button reacts on `mouseDown()` and should run a selector/action.

I don't know how to add a target and action variable to the subclass (similar to user interface elements like `NSButton`). I tried

```
var target : AnyObject?
var action: Selector?
```

Also how do I run the selector with the target in my subclass?

Comment: This question is very broad and likely the wrong solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. If you *must* roll your own button, it is probably better to subclass `NSControl`.  Better though is to configure `NSButton` properly.

Comment: @par There is nothing broad about this question. The OP has target and action properties on a custom class. The question is asking how to call the action on the target.

Comment: @rmaddy and yet neither answer to this question, yours included, answers OP's question.  Vincent suggests a solution using `IBOutlet`s and you recommend an entirely different architectural approach with closures.  These types of broad answers are the direct result of a too-broad question.

Comment: @par My answer gives two specific ways to use target/action before the suggestion of using closures. Please read my answer again.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, you did. Apologies for getting caught up in the side discussion. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "target/action" pair is archaic and should be avoided. But if you really wanted to use it, have a look at the `NSApplication sendAction(_:to:from:)` method.

Or if your custom button extends `NSControl`, you can use its `target` and `action` properties and its `sendAction(_:to:)` method.

A more modern approach would be to provide a closure property for your button class and then call that closure instead of using a target/action pair. Using a closure is safer, cleaner, and probably makes client code of your button class easier to write.

Comment: What makes you think target/action is archaic?  This pattern underpins nearly all controls in iOS/OS X and the delegate pattern (of which target/action is essentially a variant) is still a very relevant API choice for many purposes. Closures have their place, certainly, but come with their own shortcomings (most people still seem very confused about when to use `[weak self]` for example). Your answer seems to advocate tossing tried-and-true principles in favor of "the latest thing" with no clear supporting evidence or motivation.

Comment: @par There's no type safety in target/action. There's no simple way to support arbitrary parameters to the action. Keep in mind that the target/action in Cocoa was created in Objective-C long before there were blocks. It was the only approach at the time. Closures/blocks provide far more flexibility and type safely. And it is much cleaner in most cases.

Comment: @par And look at the vast number of "unrecognized selector" questions on stack overflow due to the problems of using selectors incorrectly.

Comment: The target/action pattern is inextricably linked to the dynamic dispatch nature of Objective-C. It underpins all controls because the bulk of iOS/macOS is implemented in Objective-C. I agree with @rmaddy that going forward, newer/safer patterns should be encouraged (especially if you are writing pure Swift code and are not burdened by the legacy of Cocoa).

Comment: Now that Objective-C **does** support blocks, it would be nice if Cocoa controls added support for closure/block based callbacks in future releases of the SDKs (and gradually discouraged/deprecated the target/action paradigm).

Comment: I appreciate both of your replies and I'll give them some thought. I understand my experience is not definitive, but I have never encountered a situation where type-safety was a problem with target/action, nor have I ever needed to pass arbitrary parameters using this pattern (typically a control is very tightly bound to a user-interaction with a particular view). I have personally seen many instances of closure-induced leaks, so I don't necessarily consider them safer. As I said though, they certainly do have their place, but I guess I'm not ready to completely jettison the tried-and-true.